# function failed when call it from a command in vim

Tags: vim

When I find the word in the current file, I need to first type "/keyword", but I can't see all the matched rows, So I tried to use the following command to do a shortcut, but it doesn't work, could you please help check why it failed?

```
function! FindCurrentFile(pattern)
    echo a:pattern
    execute ":vimgrep" . a:pattern . " %"
    execute ":cw"
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Fi call FindCurrentFile(<args>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change the line in your function into this:

```
execute ':vimgrep "' . a:pattern . '" ' . expand("%")
```

Comment: thanks, but command execute ":cw" doesn't work well, I still need to press enter key. So I changed to execute ":cw" .'<CR>', however it complains the trailing char is error.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, if you just need a quick overview over the matches you can simply use

```
:g//print
```

or

```
:g//p
```

(You may even leave out the `p` completely, since `:print` is the default operation for the `:global` command.)

When the current buffer has line numbers turned off, the results produced by `:g//p` can be difficult to take in fast. In that case use `:g//#` to show the matches with the line numbers.

Another trick that works for keywords is the normal mode command `[I`. It shows a quick overview of all the instances of the keyword under the cursor in the current buffer. See `:h [I`.

Comment: This is a great tip. I have always used some kind of grep, manually jumping to quickly find every match in a buffer, (or deleting all the non matching line). This is *very* useful and simple.

Answer (score 2):

`<args>` is replace with the command argument **as is** - that means that if you write:

```
Fi keyword
```

the command will run:

```
call FindCurrentFile(keyword)
```

which is wrong - because you want to pass the string `"keyword"`, not a variable named `keyword`.

What you need is `<q-args>`, which quotes the argument.

BTW, if you wanted more than one argument, you had to use `<f-args>`, which quotes multiple arguments and separates them with `,`.